# I need a registration button that sends data to a mySQL server to also Redirect on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So i am making a registration page on my website. At the moment it is more just a test then anything. I have it working more or less and when a user attempts to sign up it works just fine HOWEVER there is no change on the page. I have created a Confirmation page but no matter what i try i can't seem to get the button to redirect as well.

```
    <form name="register" method="post" action="register.php">
        Username:<input name="user" type="text" id="user">
        <br>
        Password:<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">
        <br>
        Repeat Password:<input name="rpass" type="password" id="rpass">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

From what i can tell in the last few hours of research the reason onclick and wrapping the button in a link does not work is because the type="submit" instead of "button". Is there any way do make this button redirect? If not with HTML perhaps with a JS or PHP ?

```
    <?php

session_start();  //Must Start a session.

require "config.php"; //Connection Script, include in every file!

//Check to see if the user is logged in.
//'isset' check to see if a variables has been 'set'
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("location: members.php");
}

//Check to see if the user click the button
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //Variables from the table
   $user  = $_POST['user'];
   $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
   $rpass = $_POST['rpass'];

   //Prevent MySQL Injections
   $user  = stripslashes($user);
   $pass  = stripslashes($pass);
   $rpass = stripslashes($rpass);

   $user  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
   $pass  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pass);
   $rpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rpass);

   //Check to see if the user left any space empty!
   if($user == "" || $pass == "" || $rpass == "")
   {
      echo "Please fill in all the information!";
   }

   else
   {
      //Check too see if the user's Passwords Matches!
      if($pass != $rpass)
      {
         echo "Passwords do not match! Try Again";
      }

      //CHECK TO SEE IF THE USERNAME IS TAKEN, IF NOT THEN ADD USERNAME AND PASSWORD INTO THE DB
      else
      {
         //Query the DB
         $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'") or die("Can not query the TABLE!");

         //Count the number of rows. If a row exist, then the username exist!
         $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
         if($row == 1)
         {
            echo "Sorry, but the username is already taken! Try again.";
         }

         //ADD THE USERNAME TO THE DB
         else
         {
            $add = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (id, username, password) VALUES (null, '$user' , '$pass') ") or die("Can't                Insert! ");
         }


      }      

   }

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you wrapping it in a form tag?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the whole form?

Comment: so u want to redirect your page on submit button click.??

Comment: I just updated to reflect the form tag as well and yes i want the both the user to be registered upon click and to be redirected to a confirmation page.

Comment: Simply add `header("location: thankyou.html");` to your php

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: No, don't wrap the button in a link. I don't know where you saw that, but that's some pretty bad advice (it doesn't work like that). Why don't you include your php? Without seeing it, I think mplungjan has it right.

Comment: the PHP is not mine i' following a tutorial to achieve what i want since it is my first time attempting it. Il be posting it in a min.

Comment: seriously mate,u could have just googled it..

Comment: I did. I only posted after several hours of searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, simply do

```
     else
     {
        $add = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (id, username, password) VALUES (null, '$user' , '$pass') ") or die("Can't Insert! ");
        header("location: thankyou.html"); 

     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i needed. Sadly i can't update you atm because this is my first post however you have my thanks sir o7